# Automatic exploitation via return oriented programming

Tags: assembly, x86

I need help understanding what is going on in this image: [image].

What I fail to see is what the `@ .data` instructions accomplish in combination with the `mov dword ptr [edx], eax`, especially considered that edx is popped right after.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the `@ .data` lines refer to writable memory that is used to write the `"/bin//sh"` string, which is later executed.  The `.data` section is just a readable/writable section of the executable that is loaded into memory, typically used to store global variables.

---

Here's a breakdown of how the ROP chain works:

```
pop edx ; ret
@ .data
```

These two gadgets pop the address of the `.data` section into `edx`.

```
pop eax ; ret
'/bin'
```

These gadgets pop `0x6e69622f`, or the first four characters of the `/bin//sh` string into `eax`

```
mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
```

Then this writes the contents of `eax` at the address `edx`; at this point the first four characters of the string have been written at the beginning of the `.data` section

```
pop edx ; ret
@ .data + 4

pop eax ; ret
'//sh'

mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
```

This part does the exact same thing to write the next four bytes of the string

```
pop edx ; ret
@ .data + 8

xor eax, eax ; ret

mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
```

And then this writes four null bytes after the string to null-terminate it

```
pop ebx ; ret
@ .data
```

This gets the address of the string in `ebx`

```
pop ecx ; pop ebx ; ret
@ .data + 8
padding without overwrite ebx
```

This writes `.data+8` to `ecx` and writes `.data` to `ebx`.  (Notice that the third line here is `0x080f4060`, which we can see is the same address of `.data` three lines above)

```
pop edx ; ret
@ .data + 8
```

This writes `.data+8` to `edx`

```
xor eax, eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
inc eax ; ret
```

This writes `11` to `eax`

```
int 0x80
```

This executes a system call on Linux.  [Here](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) is a great resource for understanding system calls.  We see that when `eax` is 11 (`0xb`), it is a call to `execve`, which is defined as follows:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

So then `ebx` is `filename`, `ecx` is `argv`, and `edx` is `envp`.  At this point, `ebx` points to the string `/bin//sh`, and both `ecx` and `edx` are `.data+8`.  They are both treated as strings, but since `.data+8` contains the null byte, `ecx` and `edx` are the empty string.  So the call is essentially `execve("/bin//sh", "", "");`