# What does @.data do in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have searched all of the Internet and can't for the life of me figure out what this means. For example:

```
pop edx
@.data
pop eax
```

Or with an offset:

```
pop edx
@.data + 8
pop eax
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: It's not about the CPU architecture, it's the compiler. What are you using?

Comment: What assembler do you use?

Comment: This is on a little-endian 32-bit ELF file. It is compiled with gcc. I can now see that it is actually <__data_start>:. What does it mean when an adress is just placed in the middle of a set of instructions?

Comment: Which assembler? NASM? FASM? MASM? GNU Assembler? Something else?

Comment: You did mention GCC. Is this inline assembler? Was it GNU Assembler? Can you give us an example of a complete program to observe? This just doesn't look like anything I have encountered before.

Comment: Or is this the output of OBJDUMP?

Comment: Are you asking the same question as this person? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752941/automatic-exploitation-via-return-oriented-programming